Reading data from S3 in pyflink
I want to set a datastream in Pyflink where I want to read data from an S3 bucket and do some processing with it but I'm unable to read files from the bucket i have provided a minimal code snippet and the error I am getting.
import os
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.connectors import file_system
from pyflink.common import WatermarkStrategy, Types, Configuration, Row

def main():
    
    config = Configuration()
    aws_access_key_id = 'aws_access_key_id'
    aws_secret_access_key = 'aws_secret_access_key'
    # current_path = os.getcwd()
    haddop_file_system = f"/home/sumit/AMX-Backend-V2/flink_pipeline/plugins/s3-fs-hadoop/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.19.0.jar"
    
    config.set_string("pipeline.jars", f"file://{haddop_file_system}")
    config.set_string("python.executable", "python3")
    config.set_string("fs.s3.access-key", aws_access_key_id)
    config.set_string("fs.s3.secret-key", aws_secret_access_key)
    config.set_string("fs.s3.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")
    config.set_boolean("fs.s3.path-style-access", True)
    config.set_string("fs.allowed-fallback-filesystems", "s3")
    config.set_string("fs.default-scheme", "s3")
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    env.set_parallelism(1)

    data_stream = env.read_text_file("s3://historic-data/2023/01/01/")
    data_stream.print()
    env.execute("Read S3 Data Job")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    main()

The Pyflink version that I'm using is apache-flink==1.19.0, the plugin that I used for Hadoop is from Maven .
The error I'm getting:
Caused by: org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemSchemeException: Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 's3'. The scheme is directly supported by Flink through the following plugin(s): flink-s3-fs-hadoop, flink-s3-fs-presto. Please ensure that each plugin resides within its own subfolder within the plugins directory. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/filesystems/plugins/ for more information. If you want to use a Hadoop file system for that scheme, please add the scheme to the configuration fs.allowed-fallback-filesystems. For a full list of supported file systems, please see https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/filesystems/.


You could try to put flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.19.0.jar into flink lib directory in your local environment, or put into  plugins/s3-fs-hadoop directory in flink cluster. That's because the filesystem plugins cannot be added as a jar file directly.
